# Is it possible to make multi-pages footnotes easier to read?

Tags: footnotes

on some occasions, footnotes are long enough to be spread over several pages, which can be confusing for the reader, especially when the "page break" in the footnote is between two paragraphs (see MWE below). The reader may not know that the footnote continues on the next page.

Is it possible to put a "reminder" of the footnote number at the beginning of the rest of the footnote on the next page? For example: *1 (continued)*.

And/or add something like *(continued on next page)* at the end of the first page?

Like this:

[image]

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage{lipsum}
\global\dimen\footins = 0.18\textheight
    
\begin{document}
    
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1-2]}
\lipsum[2-10]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might find the endnote package useful for really big "footnotes".  I once read a book where the "footnote" section was a good read in itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the general suggestion is not to have multiple page footnote. Because the concept of footnote is to showing the footnote text on the same page as it been marked. The better solution is to increasing the `footin` height.

I don't recommend to use this method. Having multipage footnotes are not recommended because it will break the page layout. However, this is a solution. Using package `footmisc`. And redefine the `\splitfootnoterule` to have normal rule follow with a note text '(footnote continued from last page. . . )' before the continued footnote.

However, if there is another footnote close to the long footnote on the same page, it will force the footnote mark into the next page and generate a large empty space on current page.

Here is an example showing the solution and issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\global\dimen\footins = 0.18\textheight

\usepackage[splitrule]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\splitfootnoterule}{\pagefootnoterule\footnotesize\noindent(footnote continued from last page\dots)}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1-2]}

\lipsum[2]\footnote{\lipsum[1-2]}

\lipsum[2-10]


\end{document}
```

[image]